# React table - Add a filter button to filter table rows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-table

I need to add a filter button which will have all the column names in the dropdown. After adding a particular value in the column name the table should be updated accordingly.

I am not sure if there is any API already there and how to use it.

```
<DropdownButton
   label="Filter">
</DropdownButton>

<div className="row">
     <Table structure={this.tableData} 
            dataSet={this.list} 
            sortBy={this.sortBy} 
            order={this.order} 
            hasSelectionColumn={this.hasSelectionColumn} 
            enableSelectAll={this.enableSelectAll}
            ref={(c) => { this.tableWrapper = c; }} height={500} >
     </Table>
</div>


tableData = [
        {
            id: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        },
        {
            id: 'ip',
            label: 'Address'
        },
        {
            id: 'type',
            label: 'Type'
        },
        {
            id: 'family',
            label: 'Family'
        },
        {
            id: 'softwareversion',
            label: 'Version'
        }
    ];
    sortBy = 'name';
    order = 'asc';
    hasSelectionColumn = true;
    enableSelectAll = true;
    list = [];
```

Something like this :

[image: I am looking for something like this]

Comment: Where is the `DropdownButton` and `Table` component coming from? Are those things you wrote or external libs?

Comment: they are external libs - react-components